# AppiumStudio (Windows) : No Available Teams Found

Tags: appium-desktop

Not able to configure apple developer account in AppiumStudio on windows machine. it's showing 'No Available Teams Found' while login to valid apple developer account

I am able to login to https://developer.apple.com/ with same credentials

Appium studio : 12.10.6

How can IOS physical device added to AppiumStudio on widows machine? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcfie.png)